# Delete from table rows where any of the column field is null

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to delete a row from a  table where any of the column field is null without specifying explicitly which column is null?

I am using postgreSQL.

Here's my relation schema:

```
  Column    |  Type   |                              Modifiers                               
  --------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
  id           | integer | not null default  nextval('aurostat.visitor_center_id_seq'::regclass)
  date         | date    | 
  persons      | integer | 
  two_wheelers | integer | 
  cars         | integer | 
  vans         | integer | 
  buses        | integer | 
  autos        | integer |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I see two ways of doing that:

With plain standard SQL, simply list all columns and combine that with an OR:

```
delete from the_table
where date is null
   or persons is null
   or two_wheelers is null
   or cars is null
   or vans is null
   or buses is null
   or autos is null;
```

Another (Postgres specific) solution is the comparison of the whole row with `NOT NULL`

```
select *
from the_table
where the_table is not null;
```

will return only rows where **all** columns are not null. You want the opposite, so you need to negate that `where not (the_table is not null)` The condition `where the_table is null` is something different - that only matches rows where **all** columns are null.

```
delete from the_table
where not (the_table is not null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to specify each column you could use `NOT EXISTS ... NATURAL JOIN`.

Warning! This solution is not best from performance point of view. It should work on Oracle/PostgreSQL/SQLite/MariaDB 10.3.2 and above.

Setting up:

```
CREATE TABLE the_table(
   id           integer not null 
  ,date_          date    
  ,persons       integer 
  ,two_wheelers  integer 
  ,cars          integer 
  ,vans          integer 
  ,buses         integer 
 , autos         integer 
);

INSERT INTO the_table(id, date_, persons, two_wheelers, cars, vans, buses, autos)
VALUES (1, '21/JAN/2018',1,1,1,1,1,1);

INSERT INTO the_table(id, date_, persons, two_wheelers, cars, vans, buses, autos)
VALUES (2, '21/JAN/2018',2,2,2,2,NULL,2);
INSERT INTO the_table(id, date_, persons, two_wheelers, cars, vans, buses, autos)
VALUES (3, '21/JAN/2018',3,3,3,3,NULL,NULL);

SELECT * FROM the_table;

+----+-------------+---------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------+
| id |    date_    | persons | two_wheelers | cars | vans | buses | autos |
+----+-------------+---------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 21/JAN/2018 |       1 |            1 |    1 |    1 | 1     | 1     |
|  2 | 21/JAN/2018 |       2 |            2 |    2 |    2 | null  | 2     |
|  3 | 21/JAN/2018 |       3 |            3 |    3 |    3 | null  | null  |
+----+-------------+---------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------+
```

And query:

```
DELETE FROM the_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM the_table t1
                  NATURAL JOIN the_table t2
                  WHERE id = the_table.id);
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------+
| id |    date_    | persons | two_wheelers | cars | vans | buses | autos |
+----+-------------+---------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 21/JAN/2018 |       1 |            1 |    1 |    1 |     1 |     1 |
+----+-------------+---------+--------------+------+------+-------+-------+
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=f48476da1930bbe1b70eeece4ee8a59e)**

Answer (score 1):

Took me a moment as I couldn't find a function to *actually* do the job anywhere...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_null_columns(table_name text)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    column_name text;
    sql_query text;
    row_count integer; -- Add this line to declare the row_count variable
BEGIN
    -- Get the list of column names and iterate over them
    FOR column_name IN
        SELECT columns.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE columns.table_name = delete_null_columns.table_name
        AND table_schema = 'public'
    LOOP
        -- Generate a query to check if the column contains only null values
        sql_query := format(
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.%I WHERE %I IS NOT NULL',
            'public', delete_null_columns.table_name, column_name
        );

        EXECUTE sql_query INTO row_count;

        -- If the column contains only null values, delete it
        IF row_count = 0 THEN
            sql_query := format(
                'ALTER TABLE %I.%I DROP COLUMN %I',
                'public', delete_null_columns.table_name, column_name
            );

            EXECUTE sql_query;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```